# RazorEngine Error trying to send email

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razorengine

I have an MVC 4 application that sends out multiple emails.  For example, I have an email template for submitting an order, a template for cancelling an order, etc...

I have an `Email Service` with multiple methods.  My controller calls the `Send` method which looks like this:

```
public virtual void Send(List<string> recipients, string subject, string template, object data)
{
    ...
    string html = GetContent(template, data);
    ...
}
```

The `Send` method calls `GetContent`, which is the method causing the problem:

```
private string GetContent(string template, object data)
{
    string path = Path.Combine(BaseTemplatePath, string.Format("{0}{1}", template, ".html.cshtml"));
    string content = File.ReadAllText(path);
    return Engine.Razor.RunCompile(content, "htmlTemplate", null, data);
}
```

I am receiving the error:

> The same key was already used for another template!

In my `GetContent` method should I add a new parameter for the `TemplateKey` and use that variable instead of always using `htmlTemplate`?  Then the `new order email template` could have `newOrderKey` and `CancelOrderKey` for the email template being used to cancel an order?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Explanation

This happens because you use the same template key (`"htmlTemplate"`) for multiple different templates. 
Note that the way you currently have implemented `GetContent` you will run into multiple problems:

- Even if you use a unique key, for example the `template` variable, you will trigger the exception when the templates are edited on disk.
- Performance: You are reading the template file every time even when the template is already cached.

## Solution:

Implement the [`ITemplateManager`](https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/references/razorengine-templating-itemplatemanager.html) interface to manage your templates:

```
public class MyTemplateManager : ITemplateManager
{
    private readonly string baseTemplatePath;
    public MyTemplateManager(string basePath) {
      baseTemplatePath = basePath;
    }

    public ITemplateSource Resolve(ITemplateKey key)
    {
        string template = key.Name;
        string path = Path.Combine(baseTemplatePath, string.Format("{0}{1}", template, ".html.cshtml"));
        string content = File.ReadAllText(path);
        return new LoadedTemplateSource(content, path);
    }

    public ITemplateKey GetKey(string name, ResolveType resolveType, ITemplateKey context)
    {
        return new NameOnlyTemplateKey(name, resolveType, context);
    }

    public void AddDynamic(ITemplateKey key, ITemplateSource source)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("dynamic templates are not supported!");
    }
}
```

Setup on startup:

```
var config = new TemplateServiceConfiguration();
config.Debug = true;
config.TemplateManager = new MyTemplateManager(BaseTemplatePath); 
Engine.Razor = RazorEngineService.Create(config);
```

And use it:

```
// You don't really need this method anymore.
private string GetContent(string template, object data)
{
    return Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, null, data);
}
```

RazorEngine will now fix all the problems mentioned above internally. Notice how it is perfectly fine to use the name of the template as key, if in your scenario the name is all you need to identify a template (otherwise you cannot use `NameOnlyTemplateKey` and need to provide your own implementation).

Hope this helps.
(Disclaimer: Contributor of RazorEngine)

Comment: Thank you so much, this helps a lot!  I implemented the `ITemplateManager` interface and I removed the `GetContent` method like you said.  Does the `setup on startup` section you mentioned above go in `Send()`?

Comment: It should go on application setup where it is executed `once` and `before` using the `Engine.Razor` property. However the concrete location depends on your application: For example use a static constructor, or add it to the start of `Main` in a console application

Comment: Ahh okay, that's kind of what I thought after I left the comment.  I'll put it in the `Application_Start()` method in my MVC project.  I still keep the `Engine.Razor.RunCompile` line in `GetContent()`, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct! With this kind of setup you can pre-compile all templates in `Application_Start()` as well (if you want to; this will move the initial compile time delay when sending the first email to the startup time). When doing this you use `Compile` on startup and `Run` instead of `RunCompile` in `GetContent`

Comment: @matthid What should i do if template coming from database?

Comment: @Mvcdev depends if your "Name" is unique as well: If yes you can basically do the same just read from the database, instead of reading from a file.

Comment: This answer was a great help. Just to add information, we must include namespace `RazorEngine.Templating` in the code file to be able to use the overload of function `Engine.Razor.RunCompile` as used in the answer.

Comment: This was a big help. Thanks. Personally I think this API is overly complicated and it should be as simple as `string content = razorEngine.Run(templateFile, model);`