# Antaris RazorEngine How to Recompile a template using the same Key?

Tags: asp.net, templates, caching, razor, razorengine

I'm using Antaris RazorEngine inside a sharepoint webpart to display and render my data using razor, to completely separate the backend from the frontend styling and avoid the need to recompile my component.

I make the template key the same as the file name, Then check

If the web application is in debug mode, or the template isn't cached >>Then
I **recompile** the template

The problem happens, when I try to call "RunCompile" using the same key, which is the razor file name, I get an exception that there's a template already using the same Key.

What I need to do is to delete the cached template, recompile and cache it to reflect the changes made to the razor template code.

How to Delete a Cached template?

Or How to overwrite or recompile a cached template?

Comment: It is not very clear to me what you are trying to achieve. That's why I don't feel qualified enough to write a detailed answer. However I can tell you that RazorEngine is designed with a lot of flexibility in mind. So whatever you are trying to achieve: You can do it by implementing ITemplateManager (resposible for retrieving the template) and ICachingProvider (responsible for caching the compiled assembly).

Comment: What I'm trying to do is very simple that shouldn't require any additional custom code. 
I just need to compile my template using the same key of an old cached one, which gives an exception "The same key was already used for another template!"

I think the engine should remove the old one automatically, or give me an API to delete a template from cache using its key.
very trivial and simple requirement.

Comment: It's not as simple as you think, because the cached template = assembly is loaded and the CLR cannot unload assemblies. That's why we made it "difficult" (There is a UnsafeCachingProvider which can do it) by design to remove a key from the cache (as the memory is still used). And the default TemplateManager doesn't know where the templates come from (you insert them via strings). This fact in combination with the Caching problem explains why it throws an exception (to prevent weird behavior).

Comment: I tried to inhert from DelegateTemplateManager, then hid the AddDynamic method which calls base.RemoveDynamic(key) before calling the original base.AddDynamic(key, source); 

Now I get rid of the error, and I can change template source at runtime, However, the loaded old assemblies are still in memory!!!
How to unload them? any articles about such thing ?

Comment: Yes the problem is explained in detail here: https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/issues/232

Comment: Is it possible to compile all the razors to separate AppDomain, then if the loaded assemblies in this domain exceeds a specified threshold it removes all assemblies. I'm not sure how to implement what I mentioned or even if it possible.
What does RemoveDynamic, and InvalidateCache Do ?

Comment: @matthid I ended up with abandoning the idea as in development time, front end developers update the razor file hundred times which overwhelm the process with a lot of assemblies without cleaning and detaching the old unused compilations. Please if you found a solution or workaround let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RazorEngine Error trying to send email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29803561/razorengine-error-trying-to-send-email)